# return a ReadableStream type variable from the server-side to the client-side in Svelte TypeScript

Tags: typescript, stream, svelte, openai-api

How to return a `ReadableStream` type variable from the server-side to the client-side in Svelte TypeScript?

I try to inspire me to [this website](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-stream-real-time-openai-api-responses-next-js-13-2-gpt-3-5-turbo-and-edge-functions-378fea4dadbd)
But when I return the variable like this : `return new Response(stream );`

I have this error :

> Error: Data returned from action inside /app is not serializable:
> Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs

And I don't find any solution to this issue.

I try to return the variable in binary or text type and I have also an error.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadableStream` is used by the client to read the data.
You need to use [`WriteableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_writable_streams) to write data to the stream.

You can't send a `ReadableStream` object from the server to client which is why the error says

> the data is not serializable.

You're only supposed to send basic data like strings or numbers so it says

> Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs

Comment: Just to clarify, when they use 'return new Response(stream);' in the example, they are sending the data in the same format as mine, correct?

Comment: @FlavienMathieu nextJs and svelte are not the same. Something that works in nextjs is not necessarily going to work in svelte. In the case of nextjs, the framework is taking the stream and sending it properly. In svelte, it is trying to send the js object as is, so it has that error.